# PostgreSQL SQL query clarification

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone help me understand this SQL query in PostgreSQL ?

```
SELECT sum(count) 
FROM ( 
    SELECT count, 
           time, 
           max(time) OVER (PARTITION BY post_id) max_time 
    FROM totals 
    WHERE cust_id IN %s 
    AND time < %s 
    AND type = %s 
) as ss 
WHERE time = max_time;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You have to tell us what count, time, cust_id, and type mean in the totals table.  How could we say for sure what it does if we don't know that?

Comment: I will say this, it looks dumb and there is def. a better / faster way to write it.

Comment: @Hogan: how would you improve the query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I've no idea... the column name count makes me nervous because that does not make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Does postgresql not have `RANK()` I think that is clearer than using MAX().  (Also, it feels like it should optimize better)

Comment: @Hogan: yes of course it does. But I don't think it would make a big difference whether you write `where rnk = 1` or `where time = max_time`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - This is why I think it could matter:  It is easy (esp. since it is a common pattern) to short circuit the sub select with rank.  With a function call the optimizer would need to know to refactor the MAX() to an order by before reducing the sub-select.  I'm speaking a little out of my wheelhouse but the it seems like less optimization steps to me.

Comment: @Hogan: to calculate the rank() the engine must do the same steps as are necessary to evaluate the max() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Additional comment**

To explain my comments on the OP I was having with a_horse_with_no_name, this query could be re-written as follows:

```
SELECT sum(count) 
FROM ( 
    SELECT count, 
           time, 
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY time DESC PARTITION BY post_id) time_desc 
    FROM totals 
    WHERE cust_id IN %s 
    AND time < %s 
    AND type = %s 
) as ss 
WHERE time_desc = 1;
```

I believe this makes it clearer what this query is doing (since it a more standard form.)

---

**Original Comment**

Let me make a guess -- lets say count is the number of views and time is the time that there are those views.  My guess is it is something like this.  But KM won't tell us.

In any case if that is how it works then this is what the query does:

**It gives the total views of all posts.**
(As limited by the incoming parameters)

I could explain why, but I'll wait for you to apologize for cursing at me.

Comment: You may be frustrated with the OP, but you should still try to keep that out of your answer. Remember: questions and answers are for the general public, not for the OP alone.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Naw I won't.  People can down-vote the answer if they want and I will probably deleted it - but I won't edit the comment till the OP response nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the total sum of the `count` column where the the value in the `time` column matches the latest value in the `time` column for each post_id.

The totals that are checked are limited by cust_id, the time and the type. Values for those conditions are (apparently) passed as parameters.

Comment: @Hogan count is int, time is epoch time. My question is, why is the need of using PARTITION by post_id. post_id is another field in same table. Am i clear ?

Comment: @KuriousMind - think of PARTITION here as a single line group by.

Comment: @KuriousMind: Please **edit your question** (click "edit" to the left under your question) to put all defining information there. Don't hide it in comments.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. I found the answer. Basically it's used to rank the subset of results returned and in my context, it's not required. I just needed the sum of the count. Thanks again. We can close this here.